# C++ Code with Global Dynamic Array Stops in the Sort Function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, memory-management, global-variables

I've been trying to code a user-defined array then eventually sort it out but the code eventually stops when it reaches the sort function. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int array_size;
int* array = new int[array_size];

void create_array_cmd()
{
    cout << "Please input your desired array size: ";
    cin >> array_size;
    cout << "Please key-in the numeric characters you wish to save: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Array [" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        cin >> ::array[i];
    }
}

void print_values_cmd()
{
    cout << "Here are the values you entered: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        cout << ::array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void array_sort_cmd()
{
    cout << "The sorted values are: " << endl;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array_size; j++)
        {
            int k = ::array[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && ::array[j] > k)
            {
                ::array[j + 1] = ::array[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            ::array[j+1] = k;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        cout << ::array[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    create_array_cmd();
    print_values_cmd();
    array_sort_cmd();
}
```

Also, when I add

```
delete array[];
```

at the very end of the main function, the code won't work anymore. Somehow, the code will work fine until you input more than 2 values.

Comment: What is the value of `array_size` when this line of code is executed? `int* array = new int[array_size];`

Comment: It's supposed to be user-defined. When you run the program, it will ask you.

Comment: Yes, you ask for it, but much later than that line of code is executed.

Comment: Zero? Not so sure Mr. Ninja.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`array` and `array_size` are declared as global variables and initialized at the beginning. So `array_size` will have value `0` when you are trying to allocate memory for `array`.

You can allocate memory after asking for user input or better still to use `std::vector<int>`